# INSERT INTO COUNT(*) updating timestamp automatically in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i run the below query with the following table structure under test_reports

Table_Name
Date (Current TimeStamp)
Total_Count

```
INSERT INTO test_reports SELECT "table1", "date", COUNT(*) from `table1`;
```

The above works fine apart from the time stamp is not updated and remains 00:00:00

Comment: What does the select query return on it's own?  My guess is that it will crash because you don't have a group by clause, but maybe that's not necessary with MySQL.

Comment: It returns the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the date column is set to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` by definition, you can just leave it off.

```
INSERT INTO test_reports (Table_Name, Total_Count)
SELECT "table1", COUNT(*) FROM table1
```